# Windows Phone - Save multiples files IsolatedStorage

Tags: c#, visual-studio, windows-phone-8, isolatedstorage

My application, the file is downloaded from web server and is saved in IsolatedStorage(with same name from web file).
So, i want save multiple files on IsolatedStorage, from multiple URLs. What better way to do it?

```
private void sinc(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

        client = new WebClient();
        url = "http://infassteste.url.ph/json.html";
        Uri uri = new Uri(url);
        client.OpenReadCompleted += new OpenReadCompletedEventHandler(client_OpenReadCompleted);
        client.OpenReadAsync(uri);

    }

    private void client_OpenReadCompleted(object sender, OpenReadCompletedEventArgs e)
    {

        string strFileName = url.Substring(url.LastIndexOf("/") + 1, (url.Length - url.LastIndexOf("/") - 1));
        IsolatedStorageFile isoStore = IsolatedStorageFile.GetUserStoreForApplication();
        //  Path Storage
        // *** If File Exists
        if (isoStore.FileExists(strFileName))
        {
            isoStore.DeleteFile(strFileName);

        }
        IsolatedStorageFileStream dataFile = new IsolatedStorageFileStream(strFileName, FileMode.CreateNew, FileAccess.ReadWrite, FileShare.None, isoStore);
        long fileLen = e.Result.Length;
        byte[] b = new byte[fileLen];
        e.Result.Read(b, 0, b.Length);
        dataFile.Write(b, 0, b.Length);
        dataFile.Flush();
        object lenghtOfFile = dataFile.Length;

        MessageBox.Show("Arquivo salvo!");

    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Collect all URIs to

```
List<URI> urls = new List<URI>();
```

Then go trough them using foreach loop and save files

```
foreach(Uri uri in urls)
{ 
// save files... perhaps client.OpenReadAsync(uri); ?
}
```